# Mule:Enriching a header using Spring bean method

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am trying to enrich a mule message with session variable Text code using a spring bean . Flow code

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="enrichService" class="com.enrich.EnricherService"/>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="HeaderEnricherFlow1" doc:name="HeaderEnricherFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:/txtFile" responseTimeout="1000" doc:name="Inbound File"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <enricher target="#[sessionVars:TextCode]" doc:name="Header Enricher">

     <core:component>
     <spring-object bean="enrichService"/>
     </core:component>
    </enricher>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[sessionVars:TextCode]"/>
</flow>
```

EnrichService method

public String enrichmentResource(@Payload String payload){

```
    System.out.println("Payload:::::::::" + payload);

    String result="Text3";

    return result;
}
```

I am returning the value that i need to set in session variable TextCode from enrich service class EnrichService method enrichmentResource, but it is not been set.

Answer (score 1):

The format you mention is correct, and using an enritcher is the most legible way or writting this. However I would consider removing the core prefix of the component element, as it is superfluous given that you are already using the ns core as root namespace.

Also given that you have no special entry point resolver I guess you have a single method or a very simple class, for performance I would either set a fast entry point resolver or just use the [invoke](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Invoke+Component+Reference) message processor. Also in case performance is very relevant, you could receive as an argument the message and set properties from there instead of using the enritcher.

Comment: Yes performance is very much a requirement. How can i receive a message in a spring bean. Do i need to implement Callable and retrieve message from MuleEventContext or is there any other way. Please clarify.

Comment: You could use an expression in an annotation http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Annotation , but for performance I would rather use Callable, unless that is an issue because you have a requirement to not to change your component code.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by using expression "#[sessionVars['TextCode']]". Earlier was referring expression in wrong syntax "#[sessionVars:TextCode]".